# how to to sbt assembly on a multi project

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I am having problem building a fat jar for an open source project I downloaded. As is when I ran sbt assembly, each subproject creates a jar but includes all the scala lib classes and log4j classes (even after I added "provided" in the dependency lines). There is no assembly.sbt or any other assembly instructions that I can see. When I move an assembly.sbt from another working project, I get a

```
error: not found: type MergeStrategy
val defaultMergeStrategy: String => MergeStrategy = {
```

The entire assembly.sbt is

```
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

assemblySettings

val defaultMergeStrategy: String => MergeStrategy = {
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf/.*\\.sf$") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

Can any one help me fix this? Why does the assembly.sbt work for all my other projects and fails here? is that another way to remove the scala lib and log4j classes?

Comment: could you post a link to your open source project ? What's the sbt-assembly version ?

Comment: Its https://github.com/saurfang/spark-tsne.  With your comment, I checked the plugin.sbt file and found that the sbt-assembly plugin in missing. I added in addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.0"), but to no avail, I still get the scala lib bundled into the far jars.

Comment: try `includeScala=false` as in [this example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump/blob/master/project/BuildGearpump.scala#L124). You may find other tricky stuff for assembly there as well :)

Comment: did no harm, but made no difference.